# Consuming XML and JSON in jQuery ajax call

Tags: xml, json, jquery, jquery-mobile

Not sure how to consume `XML` or `JSON` response. Working code below. When the `dataType` is `text`, I get a `String` response without `XML` or `JSON` tags. But I would like to consume a `XML` response as `XML` and same for `JSON`. What should I fix to make it work?

`Code`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    //crossDomain: true, //works without crossDomain
    dataType: "text",
    //dataType: "application/json",
    //dataType: "application/xml",
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/appName/callMe.xml',
    success : function(result) {
        //console.error(JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log(result);
        var ic = document.getElementById('xmlPp');
        ic.innerHTML = result;
    },
    error : function() {
        console.error("error");
        alert('Not working!');                  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you get a sucessfull response.

In a project that i worked on the response was held in "d" property of the result sucess's function parameter, much like the JSON sample below:

```
success : function(msg) {
        var myStuff = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
    }
```

Comment: Nope. That did not help.

Comment: What value does result.d have?

Comment: When I use `text` as dataType I get a JSON string representation. So instead of using `msg.d` I just used `msg`. So yes the `JSON` string returned by `server` is represented as `JSON` but then the `XML` is not being represented, it gives some `Object`.

Comment: I haven't tried enough XML usage in JavaScript nor jQuery to provide further advice.
Hope you can work it out :)